# Superclass with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to generate a GUI that displays results from another process/script. The Handler generates the results that are being displayed on the GUI. I need to find a way to start the process(Handler) when the GUI window is created. So I think using the Handler as a superclass in the GUI class will help achieve that.
After initiating the superclasses, I got the error below for line creating the title for the GUI window. I guess I can't initialize the Tkinter Window using this approach.

Here is a sample of the code

```
class GUI(Handler, tk.Tk):
    """GUI created from Tkinter

    Note:
        The __init__ method creates the GUI window with using a
        notebook tabbed style.

        The input fields tab is created to allow for input values
        for the experiment.
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 setup_file: str,
                 step_file: str,
                 bitfile: Optional[str] = None,
                 compact_rio: Optional[str] = None,
                 verbose: Optional[bool] = True,
                 ) -> None:

        super().__init__(setup_file,
                         step_file,
                         bitfile,
                         compact_rio,
                         verbose)

       # GUI window
       self.title("Python Graphic User Interface")
```

```
def main() -> None:
    """run the gui"""
    setup = r"C:\Users\David\crio\examples\setup.yaml"
    steps = r"C:\Users\David\crio\examples\steps.yaml"
    root = GUI(setup, steps)
    root.iconbitmap(r'../docs/tiger.ico')
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Below is a copy of the `__init__` method for the `Handler` class

```
class Handler(MultiProcessing):
    """
    Class handling communication between all processes and tasks

    Attributes:
        tcp (object): TCPServer object handling TCP communication
        fpga (object): FPGAData object handling FPGA communication
        umanager (object): @todo micromanager object (to be implemented)
        scheduler (object): Scheduler object handling stepping

        process (object): StartMultiprocessing object

        verbose (bool): verbosity flag

        iteration (int): used by save_data
        results (dict): results obtained from FPGA
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 setup_file: str,
                 step_file: str,
                 bitfile: Optional[str] = None,
                 compact_rio: Optional[str] = None,
                 verbose: Optional[bool] = True) -> None:
        """
        Instantiate Handler object

        args:
            setup_file (str): yaml file 
            step_file (str): yaml file containing the step information
            bitfile (str): labview specific
            seg (str): segment that is being stepped through
            compact_rio (str): None or IP address
            verbose (bool): verbose output
        """
        super().__init__(verbose=verbose)
```

error

```
C:\Users\David\crio\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/David/crio/crio/graphical_interface.py
[TCPServer] TCPServer instantiated: 
    parent process: 11340
    process id: 23952 

 ... resuming ramping process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/David/crio/crio/graphical_interface.py", line 203, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/David/crio/crio/graphical_interface.py", line 197, in main
    root = GUI(setup, steps)
  File "C:/Users/David/crio/crio/graphical_interface.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.title("Python Graphic User Interface")
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2217, in wm_title
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'title', self._w, string)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: We would need to see at least a stripped-down version of `Handler` (just enough to reproduce the problem) in order to make any sense of this.  Perhaps its `__init__()` is not cooperating - for `super()` to work, *every* class in the hierarchy has to use it.

Comment: The `Handler` runs I believe, that is why I have the few lines before the error output